# What is an equivalent of rm `find lib/ -name *.swp` without find?

Tags: find, wildcards, rm

I would like to remove all files in the `lib` directory with `.swp` in the end.

How can I do this without `find` in:

```
rm `find lib/ -name *.swp`
```

Comment: Why do you wish to remove 'find', academic reason or something more precise?

Comment: I'm just curious how this can be done in other way.

Comment: If you have Perl installed you can use find2perl to generate an equivalent script, which you can customise as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit to find is that it is recursive. Some modern shells offer search recursion, but it is not in the POSIX standard, so you can not rely on them to work everywhere. Here is an example that works in bash 4.0 and higher.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.swp; do
    rm -- "$f"
done
```

As far as the find command that you already have, it will break on any files that contain whitespace such as spaces. Here is a fixed example:

```
find lib/ -name '*.swp' -exec rm {} +
```

With some versions of `find`, you can use `-delete`:

```
find lib/ -name '*.swp' -delete
```

Comment: Note that that `for` loop above would rather be equivalent to `find -L . -name '.*' ! -name . -prune -o -name '*.swp' -exec rm {} +`

Answer (score 1):

```
cd lib && ls -R  | grep '\.swp$' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

As for your original, I'd have done it:

```
find lib -name '*.swp' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

because if `find` returns no results you won't get an error.

You might also want to use `\! -type d` so `find` doesn't return any directories which happen to be called `*.swp`, because `rm` would fail to remove them.  You could do something similar with my alternative using `ls -RF` because directories would get a trailing `/` so not match the regex.

Comment: Both examples break on files with spaces.

Comment: Does piping to xargs provide a benefit over -delete or even -exec rm {} ?

Comment: fixed by setting newline as the delimiter

Comment: @JonathanWakely Breaks on files containing newlines in the name :).

Comment: which is why GNU find has `-print0` but it's not portable

Comment: @user17591 - it has a benefits over `-exec rm {} \;` because it will execute `rm` one time, rather than once for each file. This benefit does not carry over to `-exec rm {} +`. The latter is almost always what you want.

Comment: @user17591, `-exec` will spawn a `rm` process for every file, `xargs` will pass multiple filename to `rm` at once

Comment: So will using `+` as a terminator instead of `;` to `-exec` (POSIX, should work everywhere).

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that